# Add code via session if a new user is registered on woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce, session-variables

I am trying to add a script to my header once a new user is registered , here is my code

**Function.php file :**

```
add_action('user_register', 'registration_save');
function registration_save($user_id) {
  if($user_id){
    $_SESSION["user_registered"] = true;
  }
}
```

**Header.php file :**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["user_registered"])): ?>
  <script>fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');</script>
  <?php unset($_SESSION["user_registered"]); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable has to be global to check it on header.php 
You can do it also with a session variable or a cookie.

**Functions**

```
<?php
add_action('user_register', 'registration_save');
function registration_save($user_id) {
  if($user_id){
    $_SESSION["user_registered"] = true;
  }
}
?>
```

**Header**

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["user_registered"])): ?>
  <script>fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration');</script>
  <?php session_destroy(); ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Maybe you have to add session_start(); to the beginning of the header.php

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work out! i've even added session_start(); to the top of my header but in vain

Comment: Have you checked if thaht action exists in wordpress or woocommerce?? @Elichy